# Can't interact with UITableView while animations are in progress

Tags: iphone, animation, uitableview

I'm trying to implement an animation that happens when a user taps one of my tableview cells.  Basically, the animation is just a little label with text like "+5" or "+1" that appears, then moves upwards whilst fading (basically like points appear in video games as the user scores them).

In the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` implementation of my controller, I'm doing the following (paraphrased for simplicity here):

```
CGRect toastFrame = /* figure out the frame from the cell frame here */;
UILabel *toast = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:toastFrame];
toast.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+%d", 5];
toast.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
toast.userInteractionEnabled = NO; // hoped this would work but it doesn't
[tableView addSubview:toast];

[UIView
 animateWithDuration:1.0
 animations:^
 {
     toast.alpha = 0.0;
     toast.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation( 0.0, -44.0 );
 }
 completion:^ (BOOL finished)
 {
     [toast removeFromSuperview];
 }];

[toast release];
```

The toast is appearing nicely and looks great.  The problem is that until the animation completes, the tableview stops receiving touch events.  This means that for one second after tapping a cell in the tableview, you can't tap any other cells in the tableview.

Is there a way to stop this from happening and allow the user to keep interacting with the tableview as if the animations weren't happening at all?

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another option may be to use `animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` (untested, from the top of my head)

Take a look at the `options` parameter and the possible flags, defined by `UIViewAnimationOptions`. Included there is a flag called `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction`. This *could* be a solution, maybe you should try it out!

Comment: Brilliant!  That did it.  The nice thing about doing it the block way is that blocks auto-retain the views from the outside so you don't need to worry about manually making sure that the temporary views aren't destroyed before the completion handler is invoked.  Also gives you the dubious satisfaction of doing it the officially recommended way :)

Comment: Five years later and you still saved my day. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing it the other way? For example, after adding toast as a subview, you can do something like this:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0];
toast.alpha = 0.0;
toast.frame.origin.y -= 44.0;
[toast performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject: nil afterDelay: 1.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

and then release toast. You can try it this way and see if it works.

Comment: Hi - thanks very much for this, this actually works and gives me the desired behaviour.  I would like to know why the block animation method doesn't work though, since that is now the recommended way of doing things.

Comment: Really, it's the recommended way now? The only reason I can think of as to why it wouldn't work with the block method is that the block method doesn't create a new thread, whereas this method creates a new thread and all the work is done in that other thread. Maybe they set that as the default behavior so as to save on resources because most people wouldn't need to have interaction enabled during animations, and for those few that do, you can use this method. Just my speculation.

Comment: According to the documentation for `[UIView beginAnimations:context:]` this way of doing this is no longer recommended (assuming your app requires iOS 4.0 as a minimum): http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW14

Comment: Ahh, i see. Good to know. Thanks for the info. I had no idea.